# Como faço o button ficar sobreposto à imagem de fundo?

Tags: html5, css3

Estou tentando colocar um botão (`button`) em cima de uma imagem e não estou conseguindo. Já tentei mexer com a propriedade `position` (`relative` e `absolute`) na imagem e no botão, e mesmo assim não consegui.

Será que alguém pode me ajudar?

Segue o código:

```css
#AHEUA {
 background-color: rgb(249,189,251);
 border: 5px solid;
 border-radius: 15px;
 border-color: rgb(215,40,231);
 margin: 20px;
 font: 16px Microsoft New Tai Lue;
 font-weight: 700;
}
 
#botao {
 background-color: rgb(195, 88, 246);
 border: 1px solid;
 border-radius: 5px;
 border-color: rgb(195, 88, 246);
    padding: 3px 5px;
 top: 10px;
 position: relative;
}
 
.modal-dialog {
 width: 30%;
    min-width: 270px;
}
 
.modal-body {
 height: 10%;
 padding: 0px;
}

div#top {
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}

div#bot {
}

div#bot > img {
 position: relative;
}

div#mid {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
 padding: 0px 5%;
}
```

```html
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div id="AHEUA" class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
    <form method=""> 
     <div id="top">
      <img src="imagens/logo.png" width="100px" class="img-responsive">
     </div>
     <div id="mid">
      <div class="form-group fonte">
       <label for="login">LOGIN:</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control borda" id="login" value="" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group fonte">
       <label for="senha">SENHA:</label>
       <input type="password" class="form-control borda" id="senha" value="" required>
      </div>
     </div>
     
     <div id="bot">
      <img src="http://i67.tinypic.com/24nkaja.png" width="100%">
     <button id="botao" type="submit">ENTRAR</button>
     </div>
    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tente usar a propriedade [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/z-index):

```
#botao {
    background-color: rgb(195, 88, 246);
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-color: rgb(195, 88, 246);
    padding: 3px 5px;
    top: 10px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9999;  
}
```

Comment: Sem o z-index e com o #botao {... position: absolute;...} eu já consigo posicionar o botão em qualquer lugar, mas ele perde a responsividade